# How to configure OCI catalog for ME51N?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, badi

We have a requirement to connect to an external catalog from ME51N tcode (Purchase Requisition). This integration must be done entirely from ECC side and shouldn't be linked with SRM.

I have tried configuring the OCI on two different places. Let me explain the results and doubts for each. I don't need the two solutions, just one that gives me what I require.

1. Path: SPRO-> IMG-> Materials Management-> Purchasing-> Environment Data-> Web Services: ID and Description

Here I was able to configure the connection to the Catalog, and after defining it as default I get the button on ME51N's toolbar to get to the catalog. I'm able to select the data and return it to the purchase requisition. However some data that the client is sending is not the same as we have configured in our materials management, e.g. if they send a material group that we don't have the received material group is deleted and I can't see what the catalog returned for that field.

I've searched for a way to map these fields, and possibly insert some Z code to map those values and fill them like we need to, but I havent found anything that is usefull, most documentation is made for SRM, not for ECC.

So, how can I map/configure these values returned from the catalog? I'm currently looking at BADI ME_PROCESS_REQ_CUST to makes changes based on what the Catalog returned, but this is too late, as not configured values have already been deleted by then.

2. Since I couldn't configure this, I tried another way, using this other path, that does give me the option of mapping the fields from the catalog to SAP's standard fields, and even the possibility to set exits to add personal logic.

Path: SPRO-> IMG-> Plant Maintenance and Customer Service-> Maintenance and Service Processing-> Maintenance and Service Orders-> Interface for Procurement Using Catalogs (OCI)-> Define Catalogs.

However I haven't been able to display a link to these catalogs in ME51N.
Can these Catalogs be linked to ME51N?

Thanks

Comment: What means you *haven't been able to display a link to these catalogs*? What is the output? Any errors?

Comment: For point 2, I have created a catalog but I haven't been able to access this catalog in ME51N, or anywhere actually. What I mean is after creating this catalog I don't have a button in any tcode to actually go to the catalog. For point 1 I have, but that one doesn't have a "mapping config".

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no catalog by my hands now, but the procedure for connecting catalog to ERP via OCI seems to be the following:

1. You should make proper customization in the path

*SPRO-> IMG-> Plant Maintenance and Customer Service-> Maintenance and Service Processing-> Maintenance and Service Orders-> Interface for Procurement Using External Catalogs*

2. To adjust automatic Purchase Requisition creation you should set item category to `N (non-stock item)`.
3. And also you should activate method `COMPONENT_VIA_CATALOG_GET` in BAdI `PLM_CATALOG_IF`.

See additional details [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/79/cfb65334e6b54ce10000000a174cb4/frameset.htm).

Comment: Thanks, but with this I don't see any button in ME51N to go to the catalog